# Почему не показывает статус активности дискорд бота?

Tags: javascript, discord

Вроде все написано верно, но отражается только статус онлайна, а именно Слушает музыку не показывает.

```
client.on("ready", () => {
   client.user.setPresence({
      activity: [{
         name: "музыку",
         type: "LISTENING"
      }],
      status: "idle"
   })
})
```